# MoviePy Error by using concatenate_videoclips: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_frame'

Tags: python, concatenation, attributeerror, nonetype, moviepy

I try to concatenate a hand full of video files (~70) by using the function concatenate_videoclips() from MoviePy. This is the code is used:

```
def merge_and_write_videos(clip_list, export_file):
    export_list = []
    for clip in clip_list:
        clip2 = VideoFileClip(clip)
        export_list.append(clip2)
        clip2.close()
    final = concatenate_videoclips(export_list)
    final.write_videofile(export_file, verbose=False, logger=None)
    final.close()
```

When i run this code with `merge_and_write_videos(glob("*/**/*.mp4"), "full_video.mp4")`, i get the following error after about 4 minutes:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\jan\Documents\process\create_Dataset.py", line 262, in <module>
    merge_and_write_videos(all_files_mp4, "full_video.mp4")
  File "C:\Users\jan\Documents\process\create_Dataset.py", line 125, in merge_and_write_videos
    final = concatenate_videoclips(export_list)
  File "C:\Users\jan\.conda\envs\python\lib\site-packages\moviepy\video\compositing\concatenate.py", line 91, in concatenate_videoclips
    result = VideoClip(ismask = ismask, make_frame = make_frame)
  File "C:\Users\jan\.conda\envs\python\lib\site-packages\moviepy\video\VideoClip.py", line 86, in __init__
    self.size = self.get_frame(0).shape[:2][::-1]
  File "<decorator-gen-10>", line 2, in get_frame
  File "C:\Users\jan\.conda\envs\python\lib\site-packages\moviepy\decorators.py", line 89, in wrapper
    return f(*new_a, **new_kw)
  File "C:\Users\jan\.conda\envs\python\lib\site-packages\moviepy\Clip.py", line 95, in get_frame
    return self.make_frame(t)
  File "C:\Users\jan\.conda\envs\python\lib\site-packages\moviepy\video\compositing\concatenate.py", line 83, in make_frame
    return clips[i].get_frame(t - tt[i])
  File "<decorator-gen-10>", line 2, in get_frame
  File "C:\Users\jan\.conda\envs\python\lib\site-packages\moviepy\decorators.py", line 89, in wrapper
    return f(*new_a, **new_kw)
  File "C:\Users\jan\.conda\envs\python\lib\site-packages\moviepy\Clip.py", line 95, in get_frame
    return self.make_frame(t)
  File "C:\Users\jan\.conda\envs\python\lib\site-packages\moviepy\video\io\VideoFileClip.py", line 113, in <lambda>
    self.make_frame = lambda t: self.reader.get_frame(t)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_frame'
```

I try do use the version 1.0.3 and 1.0.0 of MoviePy, but nether of them worked.

Comment: The stack trace suggests that `final = concatenate_videoclips(export_list)` is *inside* of `merge_and_write_videos`, but your posted code says otherwise.

Comment: Yes you’re right. This was a copy error :)

Comment: my code to do this same thing was working fine a month back, and today I'm getting the same error. I'm on python 3.10.9 and moviepy 1.0.3. It was working fine with exact same versions. I'm totally lost.